# ¿Por qué Visual Studio no se conecta a SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2017

[image]

Intento conectarme a mi base de datos local, donde están activas las conexiones remotas. Estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda por código de un tabla usando un procedimiento almacenado y me salta ese error.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Es importante que leas [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, por un lado es mejor que pegues el código del error/excepción en lugar de una imagen si es posible. Por otro, nos haría falta ver tu cadena de conexión por si el problema estuviera ahi.Para ello, pulsa en [edit] y añade toda la información relevante.

Comment: Verifique que el servicio de Windows `MSSQLSERVER` este en ejecución y verifique que su cadena de conexión sea la correcta en cuanto al servidor, base de dato, usuario y clave.

Comment: Es una pregunta un tanto genérica, pero puedes intentar la solución aportada por @J.Rodríguez siguiendo los pasos de esta respuesta en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec), o comprobar si se soluciona con alguna de las otras respuestas proporcionadas.

Comment: Te puedes conectar por otros medios? SQL Server Management Studio, Azure Data Studio, DataGrip, SqlCmd?

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate que la conexion del servidor donde se encuentra alojada tu base de datos este correctamente en el web.Config
Ejemplo:
Clase conexion.

```
   public Conexion()
        {
            string mensaje = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionApp"].ToString());
            }
            catch (SqlException connException)
            {
                mensaje = connException.Message;
            }
        }
```

ahora en el web.config agregas la cadena de conexion o mira que si sea la de tu servidor local:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionApp" connectionString=" Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Vernáculo;Integrated Security=True"   />

  </connectionStrings>
```